# Jquery limit text in text field copy safe

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is a mind Boggling question i am having trouble with. I have a text field. This text field needs to accommodate U.S mobile numbers with 4 formats

1. XXX-XXX-XXXX
2. XXXXXXXXXX
3. X-XXX-XXX-XXXX
4. XXXXXXXXXXX

When the last character is entered it needs to do a check via ajax which i have no problem with.

I need to check if the textbox has the full mobile number in when typing, copying and pasting, deleting and every possible way to put numbers in that field.

i tried checking it with $("#id").keyup but that doesn't work when you paste something.

is there a way to check either via interval or something else if there is 10 or eleven characters in that field regardless of how it got there? [edit]

Here is a solution i found

```
var checkMsisdnInterval = window.setInterval( function () {
    var msisdn = getdigits($("#newSessionMsisdn").val());

    if(msisdn.length == 10 && !checked) {   
        doPreCheck(msisdn);
        checked = true;
    } else if(checked == true) {
        //do something here
    } else {
        //do something else 
    }
}, (1000 * 60 * 0.1));

$("#newSessionMsisdn").keyup(function(){
    checked = false;
});

function getdigits (s) {
   return s.replace (/[^\d]/g, "");
}
```

it works like a bomb. Thanks for all the replies

Answer (score 0):

Why not checking it in the ajax call, use the beforeSend method and check the length of the input field.

For your reference, http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: that will not work. For example a person starts typing in the mobile number. When it get to the length it needs to be at it disables the text field and does an ajax call to see if the person is opted in without clicking buttons

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, have you looked at the change event?

http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: Does the .change event work with text fields. I was under the impression it only works with select boxes

Comment: The .change event doesn't work with my text field or it takes 20 seconds to register. 
$("#newSessionMsisdn").change(function(){checked = false;});